# Why does "-b-" differ between L “offero” and L "aufero"?

Tags: etymology, sound-change, latin

***[offero](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offero#Etymology)***

> From ob ("towards") + ferō ("bear, carry")

***[aufero](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufero#Etymology)***

> From ab ("from") + ferō ("bear, carry")

Both prefixes of them end with "-b-", but why do their compounds differ from each other, namely "-b-" vs "-u-"? Is this a regular sound change?

Another question is L "ostendo",

***[ostendo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ostendo#Etymology)***

> **From obs- for ob** ("before") + tendō ("I stretch").

***[obtineo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obtineo#Etymology)***

> From ob + teneō ("hold; restrain").

Finally, L "obs-" turned into L "os-" in "ostendo", while "ob-" survived in "obtineo", is that also a regular sound change? 
Can anyone show me some other examples?

Comment: Obstineo is also possible (think *obstinacy*), so I think different transformations happened depending on what period the prefigation happened in. As to *aufero*, that is probably mainly to avoid confusion with *affero*, from *ad-fero*, contrastive dissimulation or whatever it's called. I can't think of any other example where *ab-* becomes *au-*. Nor *obs- => os-*: I think that one is just irregular, possibly dialectical, I don't know.

Comment: Oh, there is *aufugio*. And *affugio* doesn't exist, so it's probably not because of contrast. Perhaps by analogy, from *aufero*? Either way, *au-* for *a(b(s))-* is not regular. // I can't find any other example of a verb with *os-*. So *os-* for *obs-* is not regular, but then not everything is regular in Latin. Think of compounds with *manus*, like *mancipium...*

Comment: It's best to not tack on additional questions to your main question. You should ask one thing. Your main question is also not entirely clear. You wonder if "this" is a regular sound change - but what does "this" refer to?

Comment: @Sverre, Thanks for your advice, in the main question, "this" refers to the change from "ab-" > "au-"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Latin, there was total regressive assimilation in a combination of an occlusive ([Verschlusslaut](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verschlusslaut)) followed by f:

> OCC+f> -ff-

Examples:

affero < *at-fero < *ad-fero (recomposition also possible - adfero)

offero < *op-fero (recomposition also possible - obfero)

effero < ec-fero (recomposition also possible - ecfero)

cf. Weiss 2009/2011: 172, "Latin does not normally have *f* in non-initial positions. The few examples are in compounds and the family of *inferus*."

Also note that the group "bt" in Latin was most likely pronounced [pt] (Tronskii 1960: 114). Prefixes ab-, ob-, and sub- are usually reconstructed as PIt. *ap-, *op-, and *sup- (Tronskii 1960: 113, de Vaan 2008).

As for aufero (and aufugio), here's what you can find in de Vaan 2008:

[image: deVaan2008]

In a combination of a labial/velar followed by s+C, the first consonant (labial or velar) was lost:

ostendo < *ops-tendo

suscipio < *sups-capio

suspicio < *sub-specio etc.

cf. Leumann 1977 "Neben *ab ob sub* stehen die mit *s* erweiterten Formen *abs- obs- subs-* bzw. *aps- ops- sups-*, fast nur als Praeverbien [...] Die s-Formen stehen nur vor Tenues, besonders in altertuemlichen Komposita; oefters sind sie vereinfacht zu *os- sus-*, vor *p* auch *as-* [...]" (p. 157).

Ernout & Meillet 1985/2001, "ce dernier [obs-; Alex B.] usité seulement en composition; [..] il est souvent réduit à os-" (p. 454).

So, as you can see (Ernout & Meillet 1985/2001, Leumann 1997), the form obs- was usually used in compounds.

**References:**

Ernout, Alfred, Antoine Meillet, and Jacques André. 2001. *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine: Histoire des mots*. Paris: Klincksieck.

Leumann 1977, § 203. - Leumann, Manu, J. B. Hofmann, Anton Szantyr, and Friedrich Stolz. 1977. *Lateinische Grammatik: Lateinische Laut- und Formenlehre.* München: Beck.

Pfister 1977, §137.2. - Pfister, Raimund. 1977. *Handbuch der lateinischen Laut- und Formenlehre. Band 1, Einleitung und Lautlehre.* Heidelberg: Winter.

Tronskii 1960, §232, 268. - Tronskiĭ, I. M. 1960. *Istoricheskai︠a︡ grammatika latinskogo i︠a︡zyka*. Moskva: Izd-vo lit-ry na inostrannykh i︠a︡zykakh.

Vaan, Michiel Arnoud Cor de. 2008. *Etymological dictionary of Latin and the other Italic languages*. Leiden: Brill.

Weiss, Michael L. 2011. *Outline of the historical and comparative grammar of Latin*. Ann Arbor: Beech Stave Press.

Comment: Epic answer! And thank you so much!!! May I ask you the origin of L "ecfero"? Maybe it derives from ex- + fero,  but why does the "x" change to "c"?

Comment: Alex, fantastic answer! @archenoo: In many words, *ec-* is from Greek: *ecloga, ecclesia, ecdicus*, etc. Because *pherô* means the same thing in Greek, it is possible that Latin somehow borrowed this from Greek (also possible for *ecfatus*), but I doubt it. There is probably some Proto-Latin sound change at work.

Comment: @ewawe re: suspicio < *sups-capio. Sorry, I meant to write suscipio - it was a typo, I fixed that.

Comment: @ewawe re: a velar being lost before sC: this is a well-known sound change, see e.g. Weiss 2020, page 197, rule D5. *TsT > -sT- (T stands for tenues). There are two exceptions listed in Tronskii 1960 (paragraph 268): cst is preserved or restored in formal (literary) Latin after a short vowel, cf. dexter vs. lustrum or Sextus vs. Sestius.

Comment: @AlexB.: Thanks, I didn't think about the possible role of vowel length in affecting this change